# TinyTDS timeout and deadlocks a LOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, freetds, tiny-tds

I have a relatively big system running with Rails and TinyTds (SQLServer database adapter using FreeTds). The problem is that I get around 200 emails daily saying my requests are timing out or deadlocking.

```
[Exception] application#index (ActionView::Template::Error) "TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out: EXEC sp_executesql
```

They always happen on different actions.

```
A ActiveRecord::DeadlockVictim occurred in transportes#importacao:

  TinyTds::Error: Transaction (Process ID 276) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I have no idea why it timeouts this much and been struggling with these emails for almost 2 months now.
I already tried to update the gem version, the linux binary of FreeTds and nothing helps.

Currently using Ruby 1.9.3-p484, Rails 3.2.16 and TinyTds 0.6.2

Can anyone give me some insight on how to solve this?

Comment: you are going to have to look at the sql server and see what is happening. You have queries/ processes that are both contending  for the same table in different transactions.

Comment: I have around 200 people logged on my system interacting with 30 different tables at the same time. For all of them, I open transactions to do stuff on the DB. They each have their own transaction. It shouldn't be a problem. Thyy usually are not updating the same row, or deleting a row that's being updated. Any ideas on how I must search for weirdness on the SQLServer?

Comment: might help   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot to understand more about the deadlocks. But what about the timeouts. Is it related to this deadlock problem?

Comment: Curious: How are you using freetds and tiny-tds?

Comment: Not sure on the timeouts,  do they always happen on the same queries? or any pattern? Or anything else you can discern?  Server debug (mssql and rails side, but mostly mssql) might help.  but also look here   https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds   about the timeout option in database.yml vs freetds.conf. do you have either set?

Comment: @vee what does you mean Tiny TDS uses FreeTds under the hood...

Comment: @Doon I configured the database timeout to 20 seconds and it did the trick apparently.. it's been 3 days now with no timeouts.. I also made a small cleanup on database indexes and small configurations.. I'm not really sure what did the trick, but I'm guessing it was the 20 seconds increase..

Comment: Nice.  Could be combination of the both, but more than likely the timeout.

Comment: If you wish, please add an answer so I can give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you few options that you could try..

- **By default, the Database Engine chooses as the deadlock victim the session running the transaction that is least expensive to roll back. Alternatively, a user can specify the priority of sessions in a deadlock situation using the SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY statement. DEADLOCK_PRIORITY can be set to LOW, NORMAL, or HIGH, or alternatively can be set to any integer value in the range (-10 to 10).**
- **Customizing the Lock Time-Out,When an instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine cannot grant a lock to a transaction because another transaction already owns a conflicting lock on the resource, the first transaction becomes blocked waiting for the existing lock to be released. By default, there is no mandatory time-out period and no way to test whether a resource is locked before locking it, except to attempt to access the data (and potentially get blocked indefinitely).**

*The following example sets the lock time-out period to 1800 milliseconds.*

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1800;
GO
```

- **Number of Indexes: We should determine if additional or less indexes would improve the deadlock. Additional indexes would be needed if most of the times table scanning is occurring. As well as, less indexes would be needed if unneeded indexes exists which are not used in the query plan for any queries and these unnecessary indexes need to be updated during every INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements which increases the execution time of these statements which also increase the chances of deadlocks.**